# SAMBA on server which is in a specific Windows Domain

Tags: samba, connection, shared-folders

I unfortunately do not have root access to this server. it is supported by another department so my additional information maybe limited.

1: The linux Server is connected to a DOMAIN

2; if your Windows computer is part of the domain you can establish the share connection even if you are logged into the computer with a different domain userid.

3: I am able connect with SSH or SCP to the Linux server using the Domain userid from the same computer that I cannot connect the shares from using the same domain userid.

4: if your computer is not in he the same domain as the Linux server when you attempt the share connection, you get the following and you share connection fails ( I removed domain name and userid ):

```
[2020/10/13 13:12:20.581045,  0] ../../source3/auth/auth_winbind.c:122(check_winbind_security)
  check_winbind_security: winbindd not running - but required as domain member: NT_STATUS_NO_LOGON_SERVERS
[2020/10/13 13:12:20.581270,  2] ../../source3/auth/auth.c:334(auth_check_ntlm_password)
  check_ntlm_password:  Authentication for user [xxxxx] -> [xxxxxx] FAILED with error NT_STATUS_NO_LOGON_SERVERS, authoritative=1
[2020/10/13 13:12:20.581309,  2] ../../auth/auth_log.c:647(log_authentication_event_human_readable)
  Auth: [SMB2,(null)] user [hdomain/xxxxxxx] at [Tue, 13 Oct 2020 13:12:20.581296 EDT] with [NTLMv2] status [NT_STATUS_NO_LOGON_SERVERS] workstation [DESKTOP-V8NCGV0] remote host [ipv4:10.17.66.79:65456] mapped to [hscdom]\[jhr2badm3]. local host [ipv4:10.6.235.126:445]
```

windbind is not installed or used ( as I am told ) and the message only comes up for share connections for computers that are not in the domina. Why would it call windbind if it is not installed.

I am being told it is my computer while others have the same issue. I believe the problem is that my computer is NOT on the DOMAIN the linux server is on.

Everything keeps coming back to my problem and I do not think it is I am looking to have a few questions answered that I am unable to find.

1: If the linux server is in DOMAIN XYZ does my windows 10 computer need to be on the domain XYZ and logged into the domain XYZ? ( this is what it appears ) they are testing apples to oranges. They can connect to the shares from a computer that is registered in that domain but my problem is mine is not.
( I believe it does )

2: Why would SAMBA call windbind if it is not installed? Maybe to establish a domain login where the computer is not in the domain?. I have googled this multiple ways and times without anything useful.

Comment: I am going to go out on a limb here, but I think that you are using Samba >= 4.8.0 with sssd, this is no longer allowed, hence the: winbindd not running - but required as domain member

Comment: Thank you.  yes samba is on 4.10 with SSSD and this is on RedHat 7 actually. not sure what 'Not allowed means'? So when connecting to these shares while logged into the same domain on the windows computer it works fine but not logged into the domain appears to be when it call windbind is that true? Seems the windows computer needs to be member of domain or logged into the domain. Not sure if a member is required. Sorry I appreciate this. the  support he is not looking into any of this.

Comment: 'Not allowed' means just that, you CANNOT use sssd with Samba >= 4.8.0 , it is supported by anyone, not even red-hat. If you have 'security = ADS' in your smb.conf (and I am assuming you do have, there would be no point in using sssd without it), you must install and run winbind, so you need to remove sssd.